# Multiline Captions not centered, not included in table of index when i separate them w/ {}

Tags: captions

I am trying to center a multiline figure caption, but have not been able to. When I try to separate lines in the caption with brackets `{}`, it works, except the caption lines are in reverse. I'm attaching a MWE below.

Also, how do I ensure that even if I separate the lines of the caption, that it shows up in the TOC?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in}                           

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[title,titletoc,page,header]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }  

\linespread{1.6}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\newpage

\indent X-ray generation is produced by inelastic collisions of the incident electrons with electrons in discrete orbitals of atoms in the sample. As excited electrons return to lower energy states, they yield x-rays that are of a fixed wavelength. These wavelengths are related to the difference in energy levels of electrons in different shells for a given element. This allows characteristic x-rays to be generated for each element in a material that is "excited" by the electron. One of the benefits of SEM analysis is that it is "non-destructive"; the x-rays generated by the electron interactions do not lead to volume loss of the sample, so it is possible to analyze materials repeatedly.
Figure 3 displays a typical SEM schematic. 

\begin{figure}[ht] \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{SEMSchematic}
\caption{Typical SEM Schematic Displaying Electron Source, Focal Lenses, and}{Detectors}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want – last caption line centred? On the other hand, note that usually, when you increase the interline spacing, you don't want to increase it for footnotes and captions. The set space package takes care of these details, so I took the liberty to load it and replace `\linespread` with `\setstretch`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[title,titletoc,page,header]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\linespread{1.6}
\setstretch{1.6}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\newpage

\indent X-ray generation is produced by inelastic collisions of the incident electrons with electrons in discrete orbitals of atoms in the sample. As excited electrons return to lower energy states, they yield x-rays that are of a fixed wavelength. These wavelengths are related to the difference in energy levels of electrons in different shells for a given element. This allows characteristic x-rays to be generated for each element in a material that is "excited" by the electron. One of the benefits of SEM analysis is that it is "non-destructive"; the x-rays generated by the electron interactions do not lead to volume loss of the sample, so it is possible to analyze materials repeatedly.
Figure 3 displays a typical SEM schematic.

\begin{figure}[ht] \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{SEMSchematic}
\caption{Typical SEM Schematic Displaying Electron Source, Focal Lenses, and Detectors}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does the [demo] qualifier do for the graphicx package? The centering still works without it.

Comment: [demo] is here because you didn't post any image, and it replaces it with a black rectangle.